# Missing lxml in QGIS 2

Tags: qgis, python, xml

I made a QGIS plugin in QGIS 1.8 doing a lot of XSLT transformation and other XML handling with the library lxml. After upgrading to QGIS 2.0 this plugin does not work anymore:

```
"ImportError: No module named lxml.etree"
```

What libraries do one use to handle XML and XSLT in Python in QGIS 2.0?
Would it be a mess to try and get lxml working, in regard to distributing the plugin to other computers?

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would install lxml via pip, which will probably entail installing easy_install first, then pip if you don't already have them. Further instructions are available [here](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html). Then you would type pip install lxml (assuming pip is in your path).

The other possibility is that qgis has installed a different version of python onto your system. When you say Python 2.7 is running fine on my computer - is that a standalone version, or the version in QGis? My installation of 2.0 seems to just use my 2.7 python install from ArcGIS.

Comment: I think the problem revolves around the point that QGIS on Windows installs it's own version of python, whereas on Linux QGIS uses the system install.

Answer (score 0):

You can install python library lxml alone. Unofficial installation for Windows is here: [lxml.exe](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml).

Comment: Did try that lxml installation already. Installation fails with a massage: "Python version 2.7 required, which was not found in the registry."

Python 2.7 is running fine on my computer, so can not get through with the installation.

Comment: It could by a problem  with Registry. Add Python path (C:\Python27\) to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\InstallPath.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience trying to get a QGIS plugin to work for me on Windows because of error like:

`The plugin is broken, Python said:
No module named lxml`

This is how I fixed it:

First off the principal difference between a Window vs Linux/Mac install is that the Windows QGIS, as I understand it, bundles its own version of Python.

So my QGIS python was:

`2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]`

and my system python was:

`Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]`

So when I used pip to install lxml, it was with my system python, and it got installed into the system python location, that is to:

C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\lxml

I tried initially to install the lxml file into the QGIS python installation directly with the appropriate .msi installer from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.4.4, but the installation wizard couldn't be modified to see the QGIS python (it only had eyes for the system python).

Then I tried to add this system python packages path to the QGIS site.py file as per this GIS.SE posting:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55342/qgis-plugins-with-python-dependencies.

I also tried to just copy the lxml folder to the site-packages folder within the QGIS python installation, which for me:

C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages

In both cases I got an error:

**DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found**

If I chose to keep the plugin installed, I got the following error when restarting QGIS:

`Couldn't load plugin ... due to an error when calling its classFactory() method
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

The issue lxml: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found is quite a common error reported on windows systems unfortunately, for example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228229/lxml-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found

The solution for me has been to install an unofficial lxml build from
[Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Which installs in my system python, then modify the sites.py file in QGIS as detailed above.